# Permission issues with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've been having permission issues trying to install some packages, been trying to install now with `npm install -g now-serve` and got the following EACCESS error:

```
npm WARN deprecated now-serve@0.5.1: This package is now deprecated! Please read this: https://zeit.co/blog/now-static
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ now-serve@0.5.1
  ├─┬ args@2.1.0
  │ ├── camelcase@3.0.0
  │ ├─┬ loud-rejection@1.6.0
  │ │ ├─┬ currently-unhandled@0.4.1
  │ │ │ └── array-find-index@1.0.2
  │ │ └── signal-exit@3.0.2
  │ ├── minimist@1.2.0
  │ └── pkginfo@0.4.0
  ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
  │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
  │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1
  │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  ├─┬ fs-extra@0.30.0
  │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
  │ ├── jsonfile@2.4.0
  │ ├── klaw@1.3.1
  │ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  │ └─┬ rimraf@2.6.1
  │   └─┬ glob@7.1.2
  │     ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
  │     ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
  │     │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
  │     ├── inherits@2.0.3
  │     ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4
  │     │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8
  │     │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0
  │     │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
  │     └── once@1.4.0
  ├─┬ hasbin@1.2.3
  │ └── async@1.5.2
  ├─┬ md5@2.2.1
  │ ├── charenc@0.0.2
  │ ├── crypt@0.0.2
  │ └── is-buffer@1.1.5
  ├─┬ tmp@0.0.29
  │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2
  └─┬ walk@2.3.9
    └── foreachasync@3.0.0

npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "now-serve"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/carlosgrijalva/Code/React for Beginners/React-For-Beginners-Starter-Files-master/catch-of-the-day/npm-debug.log
```

I managed to install it with `sudo` but when running `now` in the command line zsh doesn't recognize it. Same thing happened with gulp, how do I change the permission issues?

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cotd",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "0.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1",
    "stylus": "0.54.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "4.2.0",
    "re-base": "2.2.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "watch": "concurrently --names \"webpack, stylus\" --prefix name \"npm run start\" \"npm run styles:watch\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "styles": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus ./src/css/style.styl -o ./src/css/style.css",
    "styles:watch": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w ./src/css/style.styl -o ./src/css/style.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/.eslintrc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install any npm package globally, it is stored in the folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules. And there it can only be accessed by the root user. I don't think there is any issue with gulp configuration rather try to login as root user and then install that package. If still error is not resolved try checking the sudoers file of your system.